# compare two lists of strings and remove duplicates python

Tags: python, string

i Have two lists they come from two csv files, my aim is to merge the two lists and remove duplicates leaving the remaining entires in a third list. the lists can go up to 100+ entries.

If the lists match i want to just write out a statement in a csv  saying all tests matched.

Any help appreciated

List 1

```
aSD22961EC04_
aSD22961EB04_
aSD22961EA04_
aSD22961ED99_
aSD22961CM04_
aSD22961CN04_
aSD22961CP04_
aSD22961CL99_
aSD22961CR99_
aSD22961CO99_
aSD22961CK99_
aSD22961CQ99_
```

List 2

```
aSD22961EC04_
aSD22961EB04_
aSD22961EA04_
aSD22961ED99_
aSD22961CM04_
aSD22961CP04_
aSD22961CL99_
aSD22961CR99_
aSD22961CK99_
aSD22961CQ99_
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [merge two csv lists and remove duplicates python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031844/merge-two-csv-lists-and-remove-duplicates-python)

Comment: What do you mean "leaving the missing entries in another list"?

Comment: list 1 - list 2 = missing entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
list1.append((i for i in list2 if not i in list1).next())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mathing = true

for item in list2:
    if item not in list1:
        list1.append(item)
        matching = false
if matching = true:
    outFile.write('tests matched')
```

Assuming your outfile is set to the proper CSV and that you imported the lists already.